# Why can't row-oriented DB make an indexing like the inherient column-oriented DB structure

Tags: database, indexing, column-oriented

From this wiki page:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column-oriented_DBMS

I got the impression that the reason why column oriented database retrieves records satisfying specific condition faster than an indexed row-oriented database is because of the mapping.

That is, an indexing of a column is stored as the following:
1: bot
2: human
3: bot

On the other hand, column oriented database stores a column like the following:
bot: 1,3
human: 2

So, why can't a row-oriented database make an index like the column-oriented database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A database software can store data in more than one format and often it does. For example with SQL Server you can have columnar and row-based indexes on the same table. It is therefore not true that a DBMS must decide to pick one format and not use the other.

In fact it is possible to define such an index easily even with row-based indexes. Just index on `IsBot, ID` (assuming that the two columns in your example are named this way). This index can easily satisfy a query filtering on `IsBot`.